# Java: What modifier makes the object readable outside the class, but not writable?

Tags: java, access-modifiers, modifier

Java: What modifier makes the object readable outside the class, but not writable? And the object can be changed within the class.

Comment: Make a private setter and public getter

Comment: @thatotherguy That's not a modifier

Comment: There's no such modifier.  Do what Zamrony suggests.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Well that's disappointing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a field to be modifiable by its class's methods, it must be non-`final`.  There is no modifier or combination of modifiers that grants read access to such a field without granting write access as well.  Access-control modifiers (`public`, `protected`, `private`, or the absence of any of those) control the visibility of a field or method for all purposes at once.  They do not discriminate between different types of access.

If you want a modifiable field to be readable but not writable, then the only alternative is to protect it behind a getter method, without providing a corresponding setter, as another answer already describes.

Answer (score 2):

To make public read-only field, you can make field private and a public getter for this field.

```
public class Example {
       private  int myExample=1;
       public int getMyExample() {
              return myExample;
       }
}
```

Comment: Yes I already know how to do that, I am looking for a _modifier_.

Comment: AFAIK, there are only `private`, `protected` and `public` for scope modifiers in Java